# Misalignment between overlay and base layers in Leaflet web map

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, esri-leaflet, dynamic-layer

I use esri-leaflet (https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/dynamic-map-layer.html) library for LEaflet to display ESRI Dynamic Map Layer (http://gismaps.baladia.gov.kw/arcgis/rest/services/KA/ParcelLocation_MKM/MapServer) which have not EPSG:3857 coordinate system (*PROJCS["KTM_KM",GEOGCS["GCS_KUDAMS",DATUM["D_Kuwait_Utility",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",499975.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",209269.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",48.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Central_Parallel",29.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]*)

It is possible to display this layer on Leaflet web map without misalignment?

Web map example https://jsfiddle.net/8y07mcvb/

Comment: Leaflet supports only one CRS per map, so all layers must have the same CRS. If base layer is default EPSG 3857, overlay must have the same CRS. If `L.esri.dynamicMapLayer` does not offer reprojection to EPSG 3857, you are out of luck, unless of course you can find base layer with the same CRS as overlay. This is the only big advantage of OpenLayers over Leaflet, that you can combine raster layers with different CRS on the same map.

Comment: By the way, your JSFiddle does not work any more, `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` complains about too many requests.